set FileZilla to always open on your second screen in Windows 11
In most cases, Windows will remember where you last placed FileZilla. However, if it opens on the wrong screen, you can try these additional steps:

Right-click on the FileZilla shortcut (either on your desktop or in the Start menu).
Select Properties.
Under the Shortcut tab, find the “Run” dropdown and set it to Maximized.
Click OK.


Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

It is, when it is meant as a question, probably a duplicate of: How to make applications open on the correct monitor when using multiple monitors?
